# Transformar Colunas em linhas com bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tenho uma tabela em **HTML** usando **Bootstrap**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o código em **CSS** abaixo consigo que ela oculte campos automaticamente as 3 ultimas colunas quando a página é redimensionada para uma resolução de de 600(largura):

```
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        table th:nth-child(3),table th:nth-child(4),table th:nth-child(5) {
            display: none;
        }
        table td:nth-child(3),table td:nth-child(4),table td:nth-child(5) {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando clicasse somente no **+** ficasse dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tem com fazer com bootstrap ou javascript?**

Comment: Acredito que você vá conseguir fazer isso com javascript. Porque o Bootstrap até onde eu sei não trabalha com evento de clique.

Comment: @DiemanoNóbrega Pode ser em javascript mesmo

Comment: @DiemanoNóbrega, o Bootstrap é uma biblioteca que utiliza o JQuery, que é uma biblioteca para javascript

Comment: @GleysonSilva, creio que não será possível da forma como você está querendo, o que se pode fazer é, criar um modal, que ao clicar em cima do botão de "+" trará em si uma cópia dos dados ocultos da tabela

Comment: @DiemanoNóbrega verdade, acabei sendo redundante.

Comment: @MuriloGambôa boa idéia vou tentar assim, porém, pensei na outra maneira por achar ser mais fácil de implementar, claro, se houvesse uma maneira dele mudar a tabela sem eu ter que fazer código para cada tabela que eu tiver no sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de comportamento acredito que seja melhor utilizar javascript ou AngularJS. Com Angular você pode criar esse tipo de comportamento e reutilizar de maneira mais rápida.

Comment: Se possível gostaria de usar javascript, mas senão, pode ser Angular mesmo, você poderia postar um exemplo ou indicar algum site?

Comment: acredito que esse video possa te dar uma ideia de como resolver este problema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9bw7vWSKVE

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas como não vi nada de AngularJs e o projeto não utiliza esse Framework, não achei uma boa ideia utiliza-lo apenas para esse fim. Vou continuar buscando como fazer em CSS e/ou Javascript.

Comment: depois de analisar o angular 2.0 vi que é mais proveitoso eu investir nele do que continuar com Javascript, Jquery, Bootstrap sem usar um Framework.